# dotnet-try wants to access key "tmp..." in your keychain. Should I give it access?

Tags: keychain, dotnet-tool

I'm following along to an [Intro to LINQ vid on YouTube](https://youtu.be/p5myHVOtmiU?si=mOhkpXw49PR6wstv) which asks us to install [dotnet-try](https://github.com/dotnet/try-samples). So install it and run `dotnet try demo` from an empty directory as instructed. It opens up a browser window `https://localhost:<port-num>` and pops up a window saying

> dotnet-try wants access key "tmp..." in your keychain.
> To allow this, enter the "login" keychain password.

Is this legit? I opened up *Keychain Access* and searched for that key and it's not in there. There's no key anywhere whose name begins with `"tmp"`.